# Very old furnace- I need a technician to inspect it-What would be a good check up list?

Tags: furnace, inspection

First of all you should know that this is about a 25 years furnace that is very simple and that if nothing is wrong with the heat exchanger it should last forever since, IMHO, the parts are very simple, inexpensive electronic devices (relays, controller modules and so on)

The main question is this: After an inspection do I get a paper of warranty that the inspection was done properly by a licensed installer and that the furnace is going to work for a decent number of hours after that or it will say it has this and that defficiencies?

Is such a technician insured in case his work was not properly done and the house is damaged due to that?

I want him to check what is going there and to make sure I did not create any problems and give me a paper for that

What would be a check-up list for a furnace like mine? Besides finding the cause of the overheating, these are things that I know I would like to be checked:

-heat exchanger -for cracks
-dirt in coils
-right speed of the blower motor
-gas pressure
-make sure everything is grounded properly
-make sure all the safety switches are OK (flame roll-out,pressure switch,load and fan limit etc)

Answer (score 2):

No warranty is generally provided. A record of inspection is provided, with notes about what was checked and the readings that were recorded at the end of the adjustment procedure.

If you have been (as it would appear) in the habit of adjusting your furnace yourself, the fact that a licensed and insured service technician has looked at it in no way protects you from anything you have done to it, or may do to it again after the service person leaves.

Comment: The only exception would be if the inspection/servicing is part of a service maintenance plan, in which case the company should specify the types of repairs that are covered and the types that are not.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I do not need to be protected. For the money that I pay I expect him or her to tell me what is the exact status of the furnace and a waranty that the things he checked are exactly in the status he says it is. Of course anything can break but nothing will be changed after he adjusted the furnace. 
basically what I am looking for is to bring the furnace to a safe functioning status (I won't touch it anymore after that)

Comment: I can't imagine anyone would be willing to provide that type of guarantee. If there does end up being a problem, how could you possibly prove whether the inspector missed it or if it was a problem that developed afterwards?

Comment: I used the wrong word. As long as I have his paper I will be OK because I am not going to touch it and whatever problem develops after that should be covered by the insurance company. I am paying them a lot of money so ....

Comment: @user2059078 Might I ask exactly how much of "a lot of money" are we talking about? A few thousand dollars gets you a new furnace; a few hundred bucks will tell you that, yes it still works but don't be surprised when it fails at age 26.

Comment: What I pay for home insurance is not the topic here.How many is a few for you when you talk about a new furnace?

Answer (score 2):

First ensure the guy doing the inspection is actually licensed; it's not uncommon for someone to go around with an invalid or expired license and basically committing fraud. Make a call to the agency who manages the license to double check. You may be able to find a list online of everyone who has a license in your area.

Besides the issues you mention there is the ventilation and emissions to avoid the area becoming a CO hazard and make you feel better about the environment.